# How does SyncSecret in secret-store-csi-driver works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-secrets-manager, kubernetes-secrets, csi-driver

How does SyncSecret in secret-store-csi-driver works?

If we make changes in kubernetes secrets, will it reflects in aws secret-managers?
I know about the vice-versa it is true.